# how to get columns have long spaces ( multiple spaces)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below structure(`'   '` refers to empty spaces):

```
name   description
---------------------
a         yes
b       '       '
c         ' '
d          null
```

I am searching for a query that give me the rows contain empty spaces, asked for the below result .

```
 name   description
    ---------------------
    b       '       '
    c         ' '
```

this query `select * from tab1 where description =' '`; will give me only c, in my query I have many values have long spaces.

Comment: Use TRIM function, see my answer below.

Comment: Check my regexp_like answer. I think it will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user [REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm):

```
with src as (select 'a' as name,'yes' as description from dual
union all 
select 'b','       ' from dual
union all
select 'c',' ' from dual
union all
select 'd',null from dual)
select * from src where regexp_like(description,'^[ ]+$'))
```

> Edited: added regexp_like(description,'^[ ]+$') to take into account only descriptions with spaces. If there is a description in the format '  s  ', ' s' or 's ' it will not be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Use TRIM function to trim the spaces.

```
select * from tab1 where TRIM(description) IS NULL;
```

I have not tested it but it should work.

Comment: This will not be working because empty string is automatically converted to NULL. So your where statement is equal to where description = NULL.

Comment: no its wrong , and it didnt work test it by your self

Comment: still didnt work, because it will give me the null values. if i test in the above example , I will have result D with it , and it will make me confused

Answer (score 1):

with this basic query:

```
with sample_data(name, description) as (
  select 'a', 'yes' from dual union all 
  select 'b', '       ' from dual union all
  select 'c', ' ' from dual union all
  select 'd', null from dual
)
select * 
  from sample_data
```

you can pick and choose among the following where clauses to get your desired results:

```
where regexp_like(description,'[ ]')); -- at least one space in the string
where regexp_like(description,'[ ]{2,')); -- two or more consecutive spaces
where regexp_like(description,'^[ ]+$')); -- just spaces of any length
where regexp_like(description,'^[ ]{2,}')); -- just paces of length 2 or more
```

if you want any white space character (e.g. tabs, vertical tabs, non blanking spaces, etc.) you can replace the single space character class `[ ]` with this `[[:space:]]` named character class in any of the above where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE operator

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab1 
WHERE description LIKE ' %'
```

Comment: but i think this will select all the result which start with space..OP only need the column having spaces